# System.ArgumentNullException in Mono ASP.NET Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, exception, mono, argumentnullexception

I am a beginner and I don't know where to look or what to do.
Please guide me through this.

I am using mono v4.2.1 and apache2 in ubuntu 14.04

I managed to install my ASP.NET web service in the url: http://myurl/WebService/Service.asmx

But when I open it, I receive this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2) <0x40960a80 + 0x00211> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Configuration.WsdlHelpGeneratorElement.get_HelpGeneratorPath () <0x40adbfb0 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerProtocol.Initialize () <0x40a73d70 + 0x00728> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext (System.Type type, System.Web.HttpContext context, System.Web.HttpRequest request, System.Web.HttpResponse response) <0x40a72740 + 0x00103> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create (System.Type type, System.Web.HttpContext context, System.Web.HttpRequest request, System.Web.HttpResponse response, System.Boolean& abortProcessing) <0x40a72300 + 0x000c2> in <filename unknown>:0
```

This is my Service.asmx:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Service.asmx.cs" Class="ACE.Service" %>
```

And the Service.asmx.cs file:

```
using System.Web.Services;

namespace ACE
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://myurl/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

First point is, it works completely OK in **Microsoft Visual Studio** but mono has this problem.

Second point is, http://myurl/WebService/Service.asmx?wsdl opens OK in xml format but when I add it as a service reference in **Microsoft Visual Studio**, it throws exception on this line:

```
ServiceSoapClient a = new ServiceSoapClient();
```

Exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
Additional information: An endpoint configuration section for contract 'ServiceReference1.ServiceSoap' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.
```

But when I deploy my web service in **Microsoft Visual Studio** debugging mode, it does not throw this exception but mono throws it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it was because of the version of mono.

I removed all components of the official mono repository and installed the ubuntu  **mono-complete** packages and it was fixed.